# Locating header files using Cygwin

Tags: c, header-files, winpcap

I'm using cygwin and trying to set up Winpcap. I have the following sample directory structure:

`/a/basic_dump.c`

`/a/pcap.h`

`/usr/include/pcap/pcap.h`

The basic_dump.c file has `#include "pcap.h"` (which it finds). The /a/pcap.h file has `#include <pcap/pcap.h>`.

Withing the /a directory, I execute `gcc -c basic_dump.c`. However, I get `pcap/pcap.h: no such file or directory`.

I've also tried using `-I /usr/include/pcap` and `-I /usr/include` but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
gcc basic_dump.c -o basic_dump -I/usr/include/pcap -I/usr/include
```

[This](http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section1.html) tutorial explains how to write and compile C programs with `libpcap` which can be a good reference for you.

Comment: @Matt Did you try `-lpcap`? For example, `gcc basic_dump.c -o basic_dump -I/usr/include/pcap -I/usr/include -lpcap`

Comment: Yes I have. It seems as if it's not looking in the /usr/include directory.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the space between `-I` and the path to your includes.